# Delete a row with CSV?

Tags: php, csv, row

I tried a lot of things, but none of them seems to work properly... I Tried replacing the string of the file with null but that's bugged... I didn't find any csv functions that delete a row in a csv file, can anyone make this, or suggest me how to do this ? I'm a bit of a beginner, but I got experience in C# and C++ so php isn't too hard!

Answer (score 3):

Algorithm:

```
$in = fopen( 'file1.csv', 'r');
$out = fopen( 'file2.csv', 'w'); 
// Check whether they opened

while( $row = fgetcsv( $in, 10000)){
  if( ... your condition ...){
    continue;
  }

  fputcsv( $out, $row);
}

fclose( $in); fclose( $out);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function delete_line($id)
{
    if($id) 
    {
        $file_handle = fopen("your_file.csv", "w+");
        $myCsv = array();
        while (!feof($file_handle) )
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);    
            if ($id != $line_of_text[0]) 
            {
                fputcsv($file_handle, $line_of_text);
            }
        }
fclose($file_handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would $id be a string or the line number ?